# Magento admin login

Tags: magento, authentication, admin

I made a flop when I was messing a round in the configuration of admin, I change the URL base redirect to a other site we where moving to but, I am unable to log in now is there a way to remove the redirected?

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update the values in `core_config_data`

```
UPDATE core_config_data
SET value = "http://www.example.com/"
WHERE path = "web/unsecure/base_url"
AND scope_id = 0;

UPDATE core_config_data
SET value = "https://www.example.com/"
WHERE path = "web/secure/base_url"
AND scope_id = 0;
```

And make sure you clear the `var/` cache as well as your browser's.

Comment: Thank you both for your help, just took 100 try's to get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

You can look at table core_config_data in the Magento database, change the URL back there.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but sorry to say now the back end is not displaying right for me any hints?